# Parsing and calculating the sum of a column in a variable-row table

Tags: php, domdocument

In the past, I've parsed things quite simply with something like the following:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://...'));
$tables=$dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$trs=$tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$tds=$trs->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('td');
$json=array(
    "item1"=>$tds->item(0)->textContent,
    "item2"=>$tds->item(1)->textContent,
    "item2"=>$tds->item(2)->textContent,
    "item2"=>$tds->item(3)->textContent,
);
```

However, I need to parse a few things such that I can add their values together and obtain a sum to store in an array.

To clarify: Suppose there is a page that has a table. The number of rows in this table will vary, but in one of the columns, there are integers that I would like to add together, so that the sum of all rows of this particular column is stored in my array, with the exception of the first row, since it contains the column names.

At this stage, all I know is that I'm supposed to use a foreach statement to reliably obtain each row's values.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you need to parse?

Comment: I think http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm is good solution for you.

Comment: That is actually a handy reference to have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to skip the first element of the list, a `for` loop may be better. The code below totals the first column in the rows.

```
$total = 0;
$trs=$tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
for ($rownum = 1; $rownum < $trs->length; $rownum++) {
    $row = $trs->item($rownum);
    $td = $row->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0);
    $total += $td->textContent;
}
```

Comment: So in the code you provided, if I wanted to obtain the sum of, say, the second column, I would use item(1) on the $td line? I'll give this code a shot when I get home and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, `item(1)` is the second column. The code you posted in the question implies that you already know that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Just started working on this. Now, if I want to add the value of $total to an array, can I simply do `"TotalScore"=>$total`, or do I have to do something special with the plus sign that you placed after the variable?

Comment: Are you talking about `+=`? That's just normal syntax for adding to a variable. `$a += $b` is just short for `$a = $a + $b`.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I rarely use shorthand, so no surprise that I didn't recognise it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XPath provides a `sum` function that would be helpful here:

```
<?php

$html = '<table>
  <tr><td>heading</td><td>heading</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>8</td></tr>
</table>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// sum of cells in the second column, skipping the first row
print $xpath->evaluate('sum(//table//tr[position() > 1]/td[2])');

// output: 10
```